# Why is my function not alerting me "WTF" and it also does not increment i in the for loop?

Tags: javascript

i is not incrementing.
alert of WTF is not working.

```
function GameStart() {
    var TableSize = document.getElementById("table-size").value;    //  this var is 5
    TableSize++;    // now 6
    for (var i = 1; i < TableSize; i++)     // this loop works great, just coloring some cell with grey
    {
        for (var j = 1; j < TableSize; j++)
        {
            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1)
            {
                Puzzle.rows[i].cells[j].value = 1;  //Puzzle is just document.getElementbyId("Table");
                Puzzle.rows[i].cells[j].setAttribute("name","here");
                Puzzle.rows[i].cells[j].className = "grey";
            }           
            else
                Puzzle.rows[i].cells[j].value = 0;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < TableSize; i++)         // THE PROBLEM LIES HERE! it loop just once!
    {
        for (var j = 1; j < TableSize;)     // j increment is not needed since I do it in loop
        {
            var counter = 0;    // count cells with value 1
            if (Puzzle.rows[i].cells[j].value == 1)
            {
                do
                {
                    counter++;
                    if (j < TableSize)  // incase it goes above tablesize
                        j++;    // increment j;
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                } while(Puzzle.rows[i].cells[j].value == 1);    // loop for every continuous cell with value 1
                if (Puzzle.rows[i].cells[0].textContent != '')  // if cell is empty it dont need ','
                    Puzzle.rows[i].cells[0].textContent += ','; // write ',' into cell [i][0] 
                Puzzle.rows[i].cells[0].textContent += counter; // write counter into cell [i][0]
            }   //end if
            else    
            {
                do
                {
                    if (j < TableSize)  //same as above
                        j++;
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }while (Puzzle.rows[i].cells[j].value == 0);    // loop for every continuous cell with value 0
            }   //end else
        }   //end j loop
    }   //end i loop
    alert("WTF");   //THIS DOES NOT GET ALERTED!?!?
}   //end of function
```

I expect i to increment until it is out of loop, probably 5 times.
and expect the alert of "WTF"

Comment: Is there a reason you are skipping the first element?

Comment: Have you checked if your code throws any exceptions?

Comment: `i` will not get incremented only if an exception is thrown or the `for (var j = 1; j < TableSize;)` goes infinite